# Cannot run python script after pyarmor obfuscate

Tags: python, pyarmor

When I try to run the script after pyarmor obfuscation, I encounter this error:

```py
TestPolygon/dist3/obf_project/pyarmor_runtime_000000/pyarmor_runtime.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__PyFloat_Pack8'
```

I'm using python 3.11. Moreover, different scripts have the same error. With what it can be connected?

Could this be related to the fact that I'm running from an M1 Mac?

*main.py (obfuscated)*

```py
#Pyarmor 8.3.5 (trial), 000000, non-profits, 2023-09-08T17:29:25.711331
from .pyarmor_runtime_000000 import __pyarmor__
__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'PY000000\x00\x03\n\x00o\r\.........)
```

*launch.py*

```
from obf_project import main
```

> > > python3.11 launch.py

```py
TestPolygon/dist3/obf_project/pyarmor_runtime_000000/pyarmor_runtime.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__PyFloat_Pack8'

/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3 /Users/ramzangadamurov/PycharmProjects/TestPolygon/dist3/launch.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ramzangadamurov/PycharmProjects/TestPolygon/dist3/launch.py", line 1, in <module>
    from obf_project import main
  File "/Users/ramzangadamurov/PycharmProjects/TestPolygon/dist3/obf_project/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pyarmor_runtime_000000 import __pyarmor__
  File "/Users/ramzangadamurov/PycharmProjects/TestPolygon/dist3/obf_project/pyarmor_runtime_000000/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pyarmor_runtime import __pyarmor__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ramzangadamurov/PycharmProjects/TestPolygon/dist3/obf_project/pyarmor_runtime_000000/pyarmor_runtime.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__PyFloat_Pack8'

Process finished with exit code 1
```